# What is the meaning of the warning message about log(P) when calculating a polychoric correlation with 'hetcor'?

Tags: r

When calculating a polychoric correlation in R (`library(polycor)`, function `hetcor`) I get the warning message `In log(P) : NaNs produced`. I wasn't able to figure out what this warning message might constitute. I suppose it has to do with the calculation of the p-values for testing bivariate normality.

Thus my questions are:

- **What characteristics of this dataset result in this warning?**
- **What's the meaning of this warning?**
- **Is this warning problematic in terms of using the polychoric correlation matrix for further analyses?**

Data subset:

```
foo <- structure(list(item1 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
)), item2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), item3 = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), item4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), item5 = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor"))), .Names = c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", 
"item5"))
```

Computation of correlation matrix:

```
hetcor(foo)
```

Comment: the real dataset contains about 2500 rows (and more variables), but when evaluating the contingency tables a sparse matrix doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: @Andrie `hetcor` can handle ordinal variables.

Comment: Neither in `getAnywhere(hetcor.data.frame)` nor in the code of `polychor` I could find where the log is taken. So, you'd have to dive into the functions used inside those.

Comment: @Roland it's in the code for `polychor` on line 16-17: `P <- binBvn(rho, row.cuts, col.cuts); -sum(tab * log(P))`. It's in the definition of a function called `f`. Couldn't wrap my mind around the conditions that result in `P` being equal to zero, though.

Comment: @smoens as far as I can see, it throws you this as a warning, not as an error (meaning the function still performs correctly).

Comment: @plannapus Thanks. But p has to be negative to result in this warning, not only zero.

Comment: @Roland sure, you're right (and actually `log(0)` gives `-Inf` so I was plainly wrong). But still I can't see which are the conditions that would create a negative P.

Comment: Thanks for your help in trying to find out what causes this warning. I understand that it is just a warning, I just wanted to know if there were more severe underlying causes in terms of the data itself that might result in inaccurate results. E.g. if I can trust to interpret the correlation matrix and the p-values if it gives such a warning. I just thought it would be nice to figure out what was going on :-) but your comments give some nice pointers to perhaps evaluate the function itself and see what's going on there. I'll try to make sense of it that way.

Comment: To debug, you can set `options(warn = 2)` to turn warnings into errors and `options(error = recover)` to recover from errors. It will show you the stack of function calls leading to the warning (now "error") and allow you to jump into the code evaluation. `hector` calls `polychor` which calls `optim` with a function that computes a `log`. It looks poorly coded IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short (and belated) answer to a very old question.  The warning is because some of the cells in the cross tabulation of the variables (for example, variables 1 and 2) have 0 values in the cells.  This can lead to problems in estimation.

The polychoric (and tetrachoric) correlations are normal theory approximations of what would happen if bivariate normal (and continuous) data were converted into categorical (dichotomous for tetrachorics, polytomous for polychorics) data.  The normal theory approximation assumes that all cells have some value.  However, the correlations can be found with 0 cell values, but with a warning.  The resulting correlations are correct, but unstable, in that if we add a small correction for continuity (i.e., add .1 or .5 to the 0 cells), the values change a great deal.  This problem is discussed by Gunther and Hofler for the case of tetrachoric correlations where they compare solutions with and with the correction for continuity.

(See the article by A. Gunther and M. Hofler. Different results on tetrachorical correlations in mplus and stata-stata announces modified procedure. Int J Methods Psychiatr Res, 15(3):157-66, 2006.  for a discussion of this problem with tetrachoric correlations.)

Using the polychoric function in the psych package, we find the same answer as the hetcor function from polycor if we do not apply the correction for continuity, but somewhat different values if we do correct for continuity.  I recommend the correction.

See the help function for polychoric in psych for a longer discussion of this problem.