# hetcor -- can one add a correction for continuity?

Tags: r, psych

I am trying to estimate an exploratory factor analysis of a data set with 14 4-level ordered variables and 3 continuous, using polychor::hetcor.  The function returns what appears to be a correct correlation matrix, and factanal() produces a quite interpretable factor analysis from the hetcor$correlation matrix.  But the large number of warnings about NaNs produced as a result of the empty cross-tabs is a bit unnerving.

Dr. Revelle answered the underlying question in [What is the meaning of the warning message about log(P) when calculating a polychoric correlation with 'hetcor'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818139/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-warning-message-about-logp-when-calculating-a-polyc).  But I have two remaining questions:
1.  Dr. Revelle's note says that the correlation matrix is "correct but unstable."  He suggests that it will be more stable if one adds a small continuity correction (e.g. 0.1) to the empty cross-tabs.  Is there a way to add a correction for continuity using hetcor or one of the programs it calls?  Or should I use psych::polychoric instead?
2.  I am conjecturing that adding the continuity correction mostly rotates the correlation matrix, given that Dr. Revelle says that the matrix is "correct."  Will adding the continuity correction actually change the results of the factanal() function?  Can I just ignore the warnings and use the hetcor results?
Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me with the above.  Larry Hunsicker

Answer (score 0):

The correction for continuity is discussed in a paper by Gunther and Hofler (cited in the help page for tetrachoric.  The example they give is admittedly extreme, but shows the problem:

```
tetrachoric(matrix(c(44268,193,14,0),2,2))  #MPLUS reports.24
```

`tetrachoric(matrix(c(44268,193,14,0),2,2),correct=0)`
produces this output:

```html
 tetrachoric(matrix(c(44268,193,14,0),2,2))  #MPLUS reports.24
For i = 1 j = 1  A cell entry of 0 was replaced with correct =  0.5.  Check your data!
Call: tetrachoric(x = matrix(c(44268, 193, 14, 0), 2, 2))
tetrachoric correlation 
[1] 0.23

 with tau of 
[1] 2.6 3.4
> 
> #Do not apply continuity correction -- compare with previous analysis!
> tetrachoric(matrix(c(44268,193,14,0),2,2),correct=0)  
Call: tetrachoric(x = matrix(c(44268, 193, 14, 0), 2, 2), correct = 0)
tetrachoric correlation 
[1] -0.71

 with tau of 
[1] 2.6 3.4
```

Note the difference in values (.23 versus -.71).

I am not sure what you mean about the correction "rotates the correlation matrix".

This correction is applied only to cells with no data.  It is not an adjustment for small samples, just 0 entries in 1 cell.

Given that you have 14  variables with 4 levels and 3 continuous, you might try mixedCor as an option in the fa function.

```
myfactors <- fa(my.data,nfactors=what you want,cor="mixed")
```

I just tried comparing factor solutions for the bfi data set (which has 25 items on a 1 -6 scale, dichotomous gender, education on a 5 point scale and age ranging from (3 to 86) (which suggests some errors in the data):

```
f.corrected <- fa(bfi,5, cor="mixed")
```

`f.raw <- fa(bfi,5, cor="mixed",correct=0)
fa.congruence(f.raw,f.corrected) #to compare the solutions`

Which produces this output:

`MR2   MR1   MR3   MR4   MR5
MR2  1.00 -0.07 -0.06 -0.05 -0.02
MR1 -0.08  1.00  0.08  0.08  0.19
MR3 -0.06  0.08  1.00  0.09  0.11
MR5  0.00  0.22  0.12  0.05  1.00
MR4 -0.05  0.09  0.09  1.00  0.05`

Which is to say the loadings are practically identical with and without the correction.

You can see the differences in the correlations by
`R <- mixedCor(bfi[20:28])  #just look at some of the variable
R.raw <- mixedCor(bfi[20:28],correct=0)

 R$rho - R.raw$rho #compare the two solutions`

What you will see if you do this is there are a some small differences in the correlations with education.